# Take user input without main method in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

Basically I am working on Selenium automation in with TestNG, I want to take user input for one field, and to take user input I am taking help of scanner class. But it is not working without main class. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What is the code which is not working? What's the error ?

Comment: why do you need that? this would not be suggested for automation. always use argumented or property value in the automation.

Comment: @JayanthBala Basically I want to automate one registration flow, In that I wanted to enter OTP, I know there is a way to automate that too, but as of now I just wanted to take an input from user and check further, So for that I suppose I can't read data from properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static void function and then call it on your created class. Maybe it can help?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to accept input in the static method.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
  }

  static {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Sum of two numbers is " + (num1 + num2));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```